# golang build constraints exclude all Go files in

Tags: go

I build a simple "Hello, World" wasm app like:

`GOARCH=wasm GOOS=js go build -o lib.wasm main.go`

All is well. But then I want to test my code in my local (Linux) environment. So I change it to a pretty standard:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main () {
    fmt.Println("test")
}
```

And do a simple:

`go run .`

but now I get:

`package xxx: build constraints exclude all Go files in xxx`

I understand that if I specify a wasm build, I can't expect to run it locally. But I'm *not* trying to do a wasm build anymore. There are no build constraints in my `.go` source file, and my `go.mod` file just has the package and go version.

If I copy these file to a new directory and *only* do the `go run .` without the wasm build - all is good.

And if I do:

`go build filename.go`

it *works* properly.

It's like something "remembers" that this directory was supposed to be built with wasm - but I cant find what/where.

Is there a cache or something elsewhere that's remembering some build settings that I need to clear? I've tried `go clean` and `go clean -cache` - no luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer seems to be that if a filename ends in `wasm.go` - go will *assume* this is indeed a wasm file.

This means that a normal build or run will fail (if you don't specify proper OS and arch) - though a run with an explicit filename (even if it ends in `wasm.go` will work correctly.

???